# 神経衰弱の逆を目的にカードをめくるアプリ

Tags: android

http://pastebin.com/KTCkMu1p
1枚を裏返ったトランプ[img_0]､3枚の異なる絵柄の画像[img_s1~s3]を計4枚のカードとして､
画面に6枚裏返ったトランプの画像を表示し､三回連続して異なる絵柄を出したらクリア
三回目までに同じ絵柄を出してしまったらゲームオーバー
という内容のアプリを作りたいと考えています｡現在詰まっている事ｔ

- タップしたカードをどうやって1枚目にタップしたカード変数として処理
  card1 = 一枚目に出てきたカード; のように宣言し､
- if(二枚目にタップしたカード!=一枚目にタップしたカード)
- if(三枚目!=二枚目 || 一枚目)

というifのネストで処理するのはどういったように書けばいいでしょうか｡
ご教授お願いします｡

Answer (score 2):

Javaは分からないので、一般的なコーディングの仕方での回答となります。

if文をたくさん組み合わせて判定することもできますが、それよりも判定ロジックを抽象化した、こんな感じの関数を用意するほうがよいと思います。

```
boolean めくったカードが重複しているか(今までにめくったカードのリスト, 新しくめくったカード) {
    for (カード : 今までにめくったカードのリスト) {
        if (カード == 新しくめくったカード) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

あとは、新しくカードをめくるたびに
1. 「めくったカードが重複しているか」関数を呼ぶ
2. 「今までにめくったカードのリスト」に、めくったカードを追加する
という処理を繰り返せば良いはずです。
何枚めくっても、この関数を呼ぶだけで判定できます。

Answer (score 1):

contains()が使えるかもしれません。
カードが何種類あっても、めくる回数が増えても対応できます。

```
ArrayList<カード> cards = new ArrayList<>();

// カードがめくられた
if (cards.contains(めくったカード)) {
    // 同じ絵柄(過去にめくった事がある)
} else {
    // 異なる絵柄(はじめて)
    cards.add(めくったカード);  // 追加しておく
}
```